# how to print arabic text using bixolon printer?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I'm testing a `Bixolon` printer to print text .  print in English fine , but the problem is with Arabic which it prints  characters . code page is Arabic 1256

```
text = String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
```

but when i print سكر it give output ر ك س

Comment: Can you provide more code on how you print the text to the printer?